# Why can't I see the bookmarks I have created programmaticaly when testing on my device

Tags: android, bookmarks

I have an app which shows me all of the bookmarks. I can list the bookmarks then my button adds a bookmark. I have not implemented the code to update the list right away but when I return the new bookmark is showing in the list. 
Its the default bookmarks I'm adding to and I add these fields

```
 map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.CREATED, creationTime);
                map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, addTitle);
                map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK, 1);
                cr.update(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, map,"_id = " + cur.getInt(0), null);
```

the new bookmark shows in the list but when I open the browser and view the bookmarks tab all of the other bookmarks are present but not any that I have created.

I have tested this on emulators at version 7 and 10 and it works without issue but when I try it on my samsung galaxy s2 running on version 2.3.3 it adds to the list. I have stepped through on the device and the bookmark is created I know this because my code is set to add if it can't find or just rewrite if it does find.

I have more than one browser installed I've got firefox and opera on my device. Firefox keeps its own bookmarks and I haven't used opera yet

here's all the add bookmark code

```
private void addBookmark(String addTitle, String addUrl)    {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver(); 
    Cursor cur = cr.query(BOOKMARKS_URI, projection,     android.provider.Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK, null, null);
    //first find out if this title has been used before
    boolean found = false;
    long creationTime = new Date().getTime();
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        String title;           
        int count = 0;
        int titleColumn;

        do {                 
            titleColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(BookmarkColumns.TITLE);
            title = cur.getString(titleColumn);
            if (title.equals(addTitle)) 
            {
                found = true;
                ContentValues map = new ContentValues();
                map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.CREATED, creationTime);
                map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, addTitle);
                map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK, 1);
                map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE, 0);
                map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.VISITS, 0);
                cr.update(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, map,"_id = " + cur.getInt(0), null);
                Log.d(LOGTAG,"title found: "+ Integer.toString(count));
            }
            count++;   
        }while (cur.moveToNext());
    }else {
        Log.d(LOGTAG,"didn't move to first");
    }

    if (!found) {

            cur = cr.query(BOOKMARKS_URI,
                    projection, 
                    android.provider.Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK, 
                    null, 
                    null);
            // Adding a bookmark for a site the user has not been to.
            ContentValues map = new ContentValues();
            map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, addTitle);
            map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL, addUrl);
            map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.CREATED, creationTime);
            map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK, 1);
            map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE, 0);
            map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.VISITS, 0);
            cr.insert(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, map);
    }
}
```

this was the last code I tried
I set the visits value to 100 and now its showing as a history item but with a star showing it as a favourite. This says to me I'm setting one of these values wrong or missing one out. The history tab knows its a favourite but the favourite tab doesn't

```
if (!found) {
        cur = cr.query(BOOKMARKS_URI,
                projection,
                android.provider.Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK,
                null,
                null);
        //Adding a bookmark for a site the user has not been to.
        ContentValues map = new ContentValues();
        map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, "Random title");
        map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL, "http://www.bbc.co.uk");
        map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.CREATED, System.currentTimeMillis());
        map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK, 1);
        map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE, 0L);
        map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.VISITS, 100);
        getContentResolver().insert(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, map);


    }
```

Comment: the above code was from my add if doesn't already exist code. I noticed I didn't have visits and date set I've since added those and the bookmarks are still not showing in the browser that ships with android

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Given your code update, try something like this instead:

```
private static final String SELECTION = BookmarkColumns.TITLE + "=? AND " +
    BookmarkColumns.URL + "=? AND " + BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + "=1";

private void addBookmark(String title, String url) {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, new String[]{BaseColumns._ID}, SELECTION, new String[]{title, url}, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        try {
            if (!cursor.moveToNext()) {
                // No such bookmark, create a new instance
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK, 1);
                values.put(BookmarkColumns.CREATED, System.currentTimeMillis());
                values.put(BookmarkColumns.DATE, 0L);
                values.put(BookmarkColumns.TITLE, title);
                values.put(BookmarkColumns.URL, url);
                values.put(BookmarkColumns.VISITS, 0);
                cr.insert(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, values);
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jens I'll try that now

Comment: Ok, that addBookmark-method had a lot of weirdness going on. Try the edited response instead.

Comment: Hi Jens I've tried that in my code that sets the bookmark if it doesn't already exist but I still can't see it in the favourites

Comment: Jens I'm getting a bit further